# No "Proceed Anyway" option on ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, privacy

I want to go to [this link](https://feedback.appharbor.com/forums/95687-general/suggestions/2464415-support-configsource-in-web-config-specifically-i). Chrome won't let me as there is no option on the "Privacy Error" screen shown below.

I don't care if this connection is private. It's just a forum post that I wanted to look at. What can I do to force Google Chrome to do what I want?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### No option on the "Privacy Error" screen

It's not something you can override. The Firefox error screen is a little more informative:

> The owner of feedback.appharbor.com has configured their website improperly. To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website.
>
> This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that Firefox only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not possible to add an exception for this certificate.

...

> feedback.appharbor.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for the following names: ssl149278.cloudflaressl.com, *.uservoice.com, uservoice.com Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

I suggest emailing support@appharbor.com or hostmaster@appharbor.com to report the error.

Comment: Modern Firefox allows you to proceed anyway by adding an exception.